# Page Display control missing on menu items

Tags: menu-item, menu-parameters

I just moved a site from my local Mac MAMP system onto my live server.

In the admin backend, I was able to see a "Page Display" tab, while editing a menu item on the local version. With the identical site being live on my server, some tabs, including "Page Display" are missing.

Is there some global option that allows/disallows additional parameters like an "easy mode" or something?

Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe adding a screenshot can help better understanding your question.

Comment: Hard to understand what you are talking about and what's the exact issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Found an answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417351/joomla-3-3-1-cant-edit-and-create-new-menus-in-menu-manager

It seems after all, that the solution is just clearing your browser's cache.